# Need to remove - (Minus) sign at the end in number from many columns and insert it on columns removed

Tags: sed, awk, perl

I have a huge csv file which has - (Minus) sign at the end of numbers. Now I need to move these - minus signs to begin of the numbers, i.e I need to remove the last character if it has '-' sign and put the '-' sign to the front.

```
0.00,70440.19-,18.31-,0.00,451.59-,13788.77-,44.19-,6289.29-
1.03-,39.24-,0.11-,16.96-,0.00,72377.70-,0.00,146673.67-,59.11-,0.00
```

I tried the below one but if there is decimal value '.' character, then it adds the minus sign before that:

```
perl -pe 's#(\d{1,})(-)#$2$1#'g  file
```

output is below:

```
0.00,70440.-19,18.-31,0.00,451.-59,13788.-77,44.-19,6289.-29
1.-03,39.-24,0.-11,16.-96,0.00,72377.-70,0.00,146673.-67,59.-11,0.00
```

Please suggest any awk / sed / perl one liner to do this job?

Regards,
Vino.

Comment: post the expected output...

Answer (score 1):

The below one worked: Any other awk or sed solution would be great to know...

```
perl -pe 's#(\d{1,}[.]\d{1,})(-)#$2$1#'g  file
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as perl command,

```
$ sed 's/\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)-/-\1/g' file
0.00,-70440.19,-18.31,0.00,-451.59,-13788.77,-44.19,-6289.29
-1.03,-39.24,-0.11,-16.96,0.00,-72377.70,0.00,-146673.67,-59.11,0.00
```

Another perl one-liner,

```
$ perl -pe 's/([^,\n]*?)-/-\1/g' file
0.00,-70440.19,-18.31,0.00,-451.59,-13788.77,-44.19,-6289.29
-1.03,-39.24,-0.11,-16.96,0.00,-72377.70,0.00,-146673.67,-59.11,0.00
```

Comment: Please don't delete your answers like that. The downvote was mine and I would have left a comment if you had waited. Your sed solution was wrong and gave the wrong output, `451.-59` instead of `-451.59` for example. I would have retracted the vote if you'd fixed it. Also, why are you escaping the `+`? And why are you assuming that all numbers will have decimals? This approach will fail on `45-` for example.

Comment: @terdon yep. I though that was an expected ouput. Later that only i realized..

Comment: @Kasra do you know which one op wants?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: The `sed` can be `sed -e 's/\([^,]*\)-/-\1/g'`

Comment: @AvinashRaj yep ... im sorry i misunderstood the op's request !

Answer (score 1):

Another perl

```
perl -F, -lane 'print join ",", map {(/-$/ && chop) . $_} @F' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few:

1. A shorter perl one

   ```
   perl -pe 's/([\d.]+)-/-$1/g' file
   ```
2. (GNU) sed

   ```
   sed -r 's/([0-9.]+)-/-\1/g' file
   ```
3. Any sed

   ```
   sed 's/\([0-9.]*\)-/-1\1/g' file
   ```
4. Gawk. Note that the various awk variants are not very good at tasks that involve capturing patterns. GNU awk (gawk) and others can do it but I would use one of the solutions above instead.

   ```
   gawk -F, '{
               for(i=1; i<NF; i++){
                   if(sub(/-/,"",$i)){printf "-%s,",$i}
                   else{printf "%s,",$i}
               }
               if(sub(/-/,"",$NF)){print "-"$NF}
               else{print $NF} }' file
   ```

   I am sure there must be a better awk way of doing it but the above will work despite being ugly and cumbersome.
5. Needlessly complex

   ```
   perl -pe 's/\n/\n\n/; s/,/\n/g; ' file | 
       awk -F"-"  '/-/{printf "-";}{print $1}' | 
           perl -000ne 's/\n./,/g;s/\n\n/\n/g; print'
   ```